Project not getting started because of dependency
I have created a very small project by creating a controller with GET and POST methods. Its a Spring boot project with Maven. I have created controller, service and repository classes as per spring. But, the application isnt getting started. Can anyone guide me where i am wrong in this instance? I know this is a very basic spring application, wondering why this isnt working.
2024-10-16T17:17:58.811+05:30  INFO 24932 --- [spring] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1533 ms
2024-10-16T17:17:58.885+05:30  WARN 24932 --- [spring] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController' defined in file [C:\Users\PADMALATHA\Downloads\spring\spring\target\classes\com\employee\spring\controllers\ProductController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productService' defined in file [C:\Users\PADMALATHA\Downloads\spring\spring\target\classes\com\employee\spring\service\ProductService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.employee.spring.repository.ProductRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2024-10-16T17:17:58.889+05:30  INFO 24932 --- [spring] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-10-16T17:17:58.908+05:30  INFO 24932 --- [spring] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-10-16T17:17:58.948+05:30 ERROR 24932 --- [spring] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.employee.spring.service.ProductService required a bean of type 'com.employee.spring.repository.ProductRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.employee.spring.repository.ProductRepository' in your configuration.

Here are my classes
Application.java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
                                                                                                  @ComponentScan({"com.employee.spring.controllers","com.employee.spring.service","com.employee.spring.repository"})


public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ProductController {
private final ProductService productService;

@Autowired
public ProductController(ProductService productService) {
    this.productService = productService;
}

/**
 * Create a new product.
 *
 * @param product the product to create
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body of the new product
 */
@PostMapping("/product")
public ResponseEntity<Product> saveProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
    System.out.println("Saving product ");
    Product newProduct = productService.saveProduct(product);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(newProduct);
}

/**
 * Get all products.
 *
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body of the list of products
 */
@GetMapping("/products")
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    System.out.println("Get all products ");
    return productService.getAllProducts();
}
}

Productservice.java

@Service

public class ProductService {
private final ProductRepository productRepository;

@Autowired
public ProductService(ProductRepository productRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
}

/**
 * Save a product.
 *
 * @param product the entity to save
 * @return the persisted entity
 */
public Product saveProduct(Product product) {
    return productRepository.save(product);
}

/**
 * Get all the products.
 *
 * @return the list of entities
 */
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
    return productRepository.findAll();
}


ProductRepository.java
   
@Repository
    public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}

P.S I have not installed MySQL. But atleast I expect the application should be running and atleast I can hit GET API (even with mysql exceptions)

Why would you expect your application to be running? It needs a datasource, which you disabled. No datasource, no repository,  no running application.

@M.Deinum I have now started MySQL in my local , but still see the above error while startup

You have excluded the DatasourceAutoConfiguration, remove the exclude.
